# Passing with-declared variables to a custom function in Django template tags

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to build a table of 5 columns and 8 rows with the data contained in a list of 40 elements:

```
  {% for row_num in 0|range:8 %}
  {% with startrange=row_num|multiply:5 endrange=row_num|multiply:5|add:5 %}
  {{ startrange }}
  {{ endrange }}
  <div class="row">
    {% for item in items|slice:startrange,endrange %}
    <div class="col">
      {% include "shop/item_card.html" %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {% endwith %}
  {% endfor %}
```

I have successfully defined multiply and add custom functions, and I have defined startrange and endrange.

Now, I need to pass them to slice function. I've tried `slice:"startrange:endrange"` among other possibilities, but none seems correct.

How can I pass 2 (or more) variables to a custom function?

Comment: It seems you have to write a custom template filter. slice needs a string.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#slice But you cannot make your variable to string inside the template.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal Why does it need a string? Is it because you can pass only an argument into a template function?

Comment: No. It is just that this particular template filter is written that way. It is possible to pass multiple parameters if you write a customer template filter.

Comment: But you don't need to do any of this just in order to build a table. You can use `forloop.counter|divisibleby` to work out when to move to a new row.